# Find value json array swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm trying to find a specific value in my JSON.

this my json

```
[
  {
    "airportName" : "Simon Mwansa Kapwepwe Intl",
    "longitude" : 28.664999999999999,
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [
        28.664999999999999,
        -12.994999999999999
      ]
    },
    "countryCode" : "ZMB",
    "countryName" : "Zambia",
    "latitude" : -12.994999999999999,
    "cityName" : "Ndola",
    "airportCode" : "FLSK"
  },
  {
    "airportName" : "Mafikeng",
    "longitude" : 25.544469444444445,
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [
        25.544469444444445,
        -25.807447222222223
      ]
    },
    "countryCode" : "ZAF",
    "countryName" : "South African Rep",
    "latitude" : -25.807447222222223,
    "cityName" : "Mafikeng",
    "airportCode" : "FAMM"
  }]
```

now if I write this code it works!

```
for item in 0...json.count {
    i = i+1
    if json[i]["airportName"] == "Simon Mwansa Kapwepwe Intl" {
        print ("I found it")
    }
```

if I try to pass the parameter to search with a function it doesn't work, swift give me a error say :Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'JSON' and 'String'

```
func cerca (nomeApt: String){
  var i = 0
  for item in 0...json.count {
    i = i+1
    if json[i]["airportName"] == nomeApt { // error I don't know
      print ("I found it")
    }
  }
}
```

Honestly, I don't know why? any idea how to solve the issue? thanks a lot

Comment: This would be so much easier if you used `Codable` IMO. Off topic but your `for` loop is bad, it misses the first element in the array and will generate an index out of bounds error at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use decodable, 
And that will give you a simple array where you can loop and access the properties.

```
import Foundation

let json = """
[
{
  "airportName" : "Simon Mwansa Kapwepwe Intl",
  "longitude" : 28.664999999999999,
  "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
      28.664999999999999,
      -12.994999999999999
    ]
  },
  "countryCode" : "ZMB",
  "countryName" : "Zambia",
  "latitude" : -12.994999999999999,
  "cityName" : "Ndola",
  "airportCode" : "FLSK"
},
{
  "airportName" : "Mafikeng",
  "longitude" : 25.544469444444445,
  "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
      25.544469444444445,
      -25.807447222222223
    ]
  },
  "countryCode" : "ZAF",
  "countryName" : "South African Rep",
  "latitude" : -25.807447222222223,
  "cityName" : "Mafikeng",
  "airportCode" : "FAMM"
}

]
""".data(using: .utf8)!


struct Geometry: Decodable {
    var type: String
    var coordinates: [Double]
}


struct Airports: Decodable {
    var airportName : String
    var longitude : Double
    var geometry: Geometry
    var countryCode : String
    var countryName: String
    var latitude: Double
    var cityName: String
    var airportCode :String
}



func findSpecifAirport(airportName: String) -> Bool {
    if let myStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode([JsonDecoder].self, from: json) {
     let foundSpecific = myStruct.filter {  $0.airportName == airportName }
     return !foundSpecific.isEmpty;
    }
    return false
}
```

you could use it like this

```
let hasFoundIt = findSpecifAirport(airportName: "Simon Mwansa Kapwepwe Intl")
```

Comment: Don't use `try!` and since the question is about finding a specific element in the array you should include code for that too.

Comment: You are right @JoakimDanielson, I was trying to point him in the right direction instead of coding everything, I've updated my answer just in case ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert json to string, change the line to:

```
if json[i]["airportName"] as? String == nomeApt {
```